# Use PHP variable from another file when ajax is used to fetch php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This a bit complicated situation I have myself in. I have a PHP file in which I am generating data from DB dynamically. More like when a page is scrolled then data is fetched. So I have two PHP files file1.php and file2.php. file1.php has an ajax that fetches data from file2.php and displays it on its page.

Ajax in file1.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var limit = 4;
            var start = 0;
            var action = 'inactive';
            function load_posts_data(limit,start)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "fetch-message.php",
                    method : "POST",
                    data : {limit:limit,start:start},
                    cache : false,
                    success : function(data)
                    {
                        $('#message_body').append(data);
                        if(data=='')
                            action = 'active';
                        else
                            action = 'inactive';
                    }   
                });
            }
            if(action=='inactive'){
                action = 'active';
                load_posts_data(limit,start);
            }
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>$("#message_body").height()&& action=="inactive"){
                    action = 'active';
                    start = start + limit;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        load_posts_data(limit,start);

                    },100);
                }
            });

        });
```

Now, file2.php has codes which are extracting data from DB 4 at a time. The problem is that I need to use a variable in file2.php say (variable name, var) which is in file1.php and I have failed to find any solution online. Please help.

Comment: Just send data like in your code limit and start

Comment: Tried but for some reason the ajax is not working.

Answer (score 0):

***You can't directly access PHP variables from Javascript or vice versa*** ! **period**. but what you can do instead is while returning the response from the `file2.php` (where you echo or pass the response according to the ajax call) you can return an array with all the required variable values like this.

```
return array = [
   'data' => $data,
   'var1  => $var1,
   .
   .
   'varN' => $varN,
];
```

and from javascript where you process the response you can simply parse the response, for further reading you can google about :*`parsing json in javascript*

Comment: I have very little knowledge about this. I'll read about it and try to use it as a fix. If it works I'll get back. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah. That's perfectly fine.